# Xml comparison and merge tool

Tags: xml, merge, diff, compare

I need a tool for comparing and merging two xml-files.

Requirements

- Handle large Files (> 50mb)
- Collapse XmlNodes in UI
- Support validation of files
- merge files in both directions
- edit files in ui

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an application that does exactly what you're requesting, I'm afraid, but until somebody else chips in with a better answer, two free tools I use pretty much every day, that in combination would do the trick, are:

[XmlMarker](http://symbolclick.com/)
   [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/)

Comment: Two 50mb xml files caused the tool to crash.

Answer (score 0):

XMLMax will do this. It allows you to load multiple large xml files in separate instances because it uses at most 20mb memory per file. you can cut/copy/paste xml fragments between the documents. You need only select the start element, then Ctrl +C will copy the entire fragment, regardless of how large it is(tested to 10Gb). treeview is extremely fast even with multi-gigabyte size files. it supports schema and dtd validation, including inline dtd.
Google it: xmlmax editor. 30 day trial has not limitations.